Javascript Fetch API with Promises - Passing HTTP response code
I'm using the following code to make HTTP requests to my API:
fetch('api/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(jsonObj)
})
    .then(response => {
        responseClone = response.clone();
        if (!response.ok) {
            console.log(`HTTP ERROR STATUS CODE: ${response.status}`);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        processDataFromServer(data);
    }, function (rejectionReason) {
        console.log('JSON Parsing Error:', rejectionReason, responseClone);
        responseClone.text()
            .then(function (bodyText) {
                console.log('Cannot parse as JSON:', bodyText);
            });
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error: " + error)
        deplayError(error);
    });

The code works! The only change I want to do is to pass response.status to my processDataFromServer(data) function. Something like processDataFromServer(data, response.status).
Since response.json() is a promise, I cannot return a promise and a property at the same time to my next method. Any Idea how it can be done?

processDataFromServer(await response.json(), response.status)?

Refactor this using async and await and it will be easier.

It will be easier if you rewrite your code as an async function and use await. Something like this:
async function retrieve() {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('api/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(jsonObj)
        });
        const responseClone = response.clone();
        if (!response.ok) {
            console.log(`HTTP ERROR STATUS CODE: ${response.status}`);
        }
        try {
            const data = await response.json();
            processDataFromServer(data, response.status);
        } catch (rejectionReason) {
            console.log('JSON Parsing Error:', rejectionReason, responseClone);
            const bodyText = await responseClone.text();
            console.log('Cannot parse as JSON:', bodyText);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error)
        deplayError(error);
    }
}

retrieve();

Without async
As you mention in comments you'd like to stick with the .then chain, here is an alternative:
You can combine the promise response.json() with the response.status in an array and pass that to Promise.all. This will resolve to both the data and the status.
So change this:
return response.json();

To:
return Promise.all([response.json(), response.status]);

And receive the resolved values in the next then callback, by changing this:
.then(function (data) {

To:
.then(function ([data, status]) {

...and now you have access to status for your call to processDataFromServer.

your suggest is correct. But I haven't used async/await throughout my project, and for consistency, I would like to stick with it (unless someone convinces me that its impossible to achieve it just using promises).

I think I see what you mean, but this code uses promises just as well. I guess you mean you don't want to use async for some reason?

See addition to answer.

That's awesome!
